# Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: A valid cookie salt is required. Please set Cookie::$salt

Tags: php, cookies, kohana

I'm working through this tutorial (http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/04/kohana-tutorial-beginners/) and have run into this error message:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: A valid cookie salt is required. Please set Cookie::$salt.
```

I'm a n00b and don't even know where to look for `Cookie::$salt` in the app.

Answer (score 12):

You have to provide a salt as you can read in the [official documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/cookies)

```
//bootstrap.php
Cookie::$salt = 'foobar';
```

I can highly recommend the official doc as well as the [API browser](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api). When you learn how Kohana works, you will learn first of all the meaning of the error messages and how you can handle them yourself

Answer (score 1):

Find file: bootstrap.php (www\kohana\application).

Paste this:

Cookie::$salt = 'foobar';

That will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the bootstrap.php file by default. I've added it to the file, after Kohana::modules and before the routes. and it is working fine now... (copied)