# set cookie using kohana framework

Tags: php, cookies, kohana

I am try to set cookie using kohana.

I have one controller in `application/controller/landing_page.php`

```
<?php
class Landing_Page_Controller extends Controller {
      public function index() {
         // here i want to set cookie
      }
}
?>
```

and i have cookie class in `application/classes/cookie.php`

```
<?php
class Cookie extends Kohana_Cookie {

    // Set a new salt
    public $salt = "some new better random salt phrase";
}
?>
```

How can I use cookie class inside my controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set cookie in kohana framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802610/how-to-set-cookie-in-kohana-framework) (+ you can [set a salt in bootstrap.php directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357998/kohana-exception-0-a-valid-cookie-salt-is-required-please-set-cookiesal/16358731#16358731), no need for extra class)

Answer (score 1):

Not a big Kohana user, but it seems as if you should just be able to use the following:

```
Cookie::set('key_name', 'value');
$value = Cookie::get('key_name', 'default value');
```

Found the info here: http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=sessions_and_cookies

Comment: Check through the link I provided. They mention `Cookie::$expiration = 43200;`

Comment: its return error Access to undeclared static property: cookie::$expiration

Answer (score 0):

Here it the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/cookies).

By default, cookies are stored until the browser is closed. To use a specific lifetime, change the `Cookie::$expiration` setting:

```
// Set cookies to expire after 1 week
Cookie::$expiration = 604800;

// Alternative to using raw integers, for better clarity
Cookie::$expiration = Date::WEEK;
```